# Intellij doExecute not firing with DefaultProgramRunner

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm trying to develop a plugin for Intellij which will use Debugger.

I'm using this repo as an example, but in my case **doExecute** never being executed.

https://github.com/mulesoft-labs/data-weave-intellij-plugin/blob/master/data-weave-plugin/src/main/java/org/mule/tooling/lang/dw/debug/WeaveDebuggerRunner.java

so in my File only **execute** method being executed. Any idea why is it like that?

Update: since the ProgramRunner defined in plugin.xml and I need to have **RunProfileState state** I can't fire method on my own.

```
public class StudioScriptDebuggerRunner extends DefaultProgramRunner {
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public String getRunnerId() {
        return "StudioScriptDebuggerRunner";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canRun(@NotNull String executorId, @NotNull RunProfile profile) {
        return executorId.equals(DefaultDebugExecutor.EXECUTOR_ID) && profile instanceof StudioDebuggerRunConfiguration;
    }

    @Override
    protected RunContentDescriptor doExecute(@NotNull RunProfileState state, @NotNull ExecutionEnvironment env) throws ExecutionException {
        FileDocumentManager.getInstance().saveAllDocuments();
        return super.doExecute(state, env);
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(@NotNull ExecutionEnvironment environment) throws ExecutionException {
        FileDocumentManager.getInstance().saveAllDocuments();


        Project[] projects = ProjectManager.getInstance().getOpenProjects();
        StudioConfigurationProvider config = StudioConfigurationProvider.getInstance(projects[0]);

        RunContentDescriptor descriptor = XDebuggerManager.getInstance(environment.getProject()).startSession(environment, new XDebugProcessStarter() {
            @NotNull
            public XDebugProcess start(@NotNull XDebugSession session) throws ExecutionException {
                final SDAPIClient client = new SDAPIClient(config.getHostname(), config.getUsername(), config.getPassword(), "StudioDebuggerClient");
                client.createSession();
                return new StudioDebuggerProcess(session, client);
            }
        }).getRunContentDescriptor();

        environment.setContentToReuse(descriptor);
    }

}
```

plugin.xml

```
<programRunner id="StudioScriptDebuggerRunner" implementation="com.binarysushi.studio.debugger.StudioScriptDebuggerRunner" order="last"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as i can see the only place where the 'doExecute()' method is called is in it's own method body. As long as it is not called anywhere else it will not execute. I would try to incorporate it somewhere outside of the method 'doExecute()'.

Comment: doExecute is not called on its own method body, if you check github repo, it is also the same. And since it is fired from plugin.xml and I need to have (RunProfileState state), I can't call this method on its own body.